# Can't get mapbox onsubmit to show marker

Tags: javascript, closures, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Hey guys I am trying to have a button submit a point to display on the mapbox map. I am having trouble getting the click handler in the correct scope.

Right now I define my js like so to display the map and define the handler:

```
window.onload = function(){

(function(){

L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoidHJlYmVrMSIsImEiOiJjaWo0c2ZtYzYwMDN3dGhtMzhremFtMW8wIn0.dBWgVtzgwok3cCi7p5euCg';
var container = document.getElementById('container');

var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets').setView([37.7749300,-122.4194200], 12); 

map.featureLayer.setGeoJSON(geojson);

// var newMarkerGroup = new L.LayerGroup();
    map.on('click', function(e){
       var newMarker = new L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map);     
    });

return{

    mboxsubmit: function(event){

        event.preventDefault();
        var query = document.getElementById('mboxplace').value; 

        var map = document.getElementById('map'); 
        var newMarker = new L.marker({lat: 37.7749300, lng: -122.4194200 }).addTo(map);

        document.getElementById('mboxplace').value = '';  
    }


};

})();


}
```

In the HTML I have a form:

```
<div id='container'>

        <div id='map'></div>
        <br/>
        <form onsubmit="mboxsubmit(event)" name="mboxform" id="mboxform">
            Search: <input id="mboxplace" name="mboxtext" type="text placeholder ="input a place to locate">
            <input id="mboxsub" type="submit"></input>
        </form>

        <a href="/"><button>Go Back to Home Page</button></a>
        <br/>
    </div>
```

No matter what I do I cannot get mboxsubmit defined. I tried using the container as a closure scope but that didn't work either. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

First off, there's a syntax error in your HTML. You forgot the closing quote for the `type` attribute:

```
<input id="mboxplace" name="mboxtext" type="text placeholder ="input a place to locate">
```

Should be:

```
<input id="mboxplace" name="mboxtext" type="text" placeholder ="input a place to locate">
```

Your actual problem is that your function returns an object which doesn't get assigned. You need to assign it to a variable in your global scope if you want to access it in your onsubmit event:

```
window.onload = function () {
    // Assign return object
    window.obj = (function () {
        return  {
            mboxsubmit: function (event) {
                alert('Fire!');
            }
        };
    })();
}
```

Now you can use it by calling `obj.mboxsubmit`:

```
<form onsubmit="obj.mboxsubmit()"></form>
```